# How to reproduce Bash HMAC encryption in Node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, openssl, cryptography

I have this shell snippet that I need to reproduce in Node.js

```
echo "hellokev" | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 -hmac "mysecret" | openssl base64;
```

My current Node attempt is:

```
node -e "
var crypto = require('crypto');
var credential = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 'mysecret').update('hellokev').digest('base64')
console.log(credential);
";
```

Which does not produce the same output. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` appends a newline as its gets fed into your `openssl dgst` command. To make your outputs be equal, you can use one of the following approaches:

- Use `echo -n "hellokev"`, instructing `echo` to omit the newline.
- Use `printf "hellokev"` for a better, more portable way of printing in the shell. `printf` does not append a newline unless you tell it to.
- Append `\n` to your input to the `update()` function, like `.update('hellokv\n')`, if you are not allowed to modify the shell snippet.